# sql how to put data in array from table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a car table, car details table and car tags.

if I select these tables I want to have all tags as array how can I do it ?

€: In car_tags table I have this:

```
car_id |  tag
1      |   sport
1      |   coupe
```

I want all this from another table in one

code:

```
    cars.id,
      cars.name,  
      cars.cover,

      car_details.category,
      car_details.max_kmh,
      car_details.producer,
      car_details.model,
      car_details.fuel,
      car_details.engine,
      car_details.ps,

      car_tag.tag <- all tags with same car id in array

      FROM car_details

      INNER JOIN cars
      ON car_details.car_id = cars.id

      INNER JOIN car_tags
      ON car_tag.car_id = cars.id
```

Comment: Please update your question with some sample data and the result you want to achieve based on that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for information on the web regarding PostgreSQL documentation, I guess this could help you: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-array_agg/

One example for you could be:

```
SELECT
  cars.id,
  cars.name,
  cars.cover,
  car_details.category,
  car_details.max_kmh,
  car_details.producer,
  car_details.model,
  car_details.fuel,
  car_details.engine,
  car_details.ps,
  ARRAY_AGG(car_tags.tag) AS tags
FROM car_details
INNER JOIN cars ON car_details.car_id = cars.id
LEFT JOIN car_tags ON car_tags.car_id = cars.id
GROUP BY
  cars.id,
  car_details.category,
  car_details.max_kmh,
  car_details.producer,
  car_details.model,
  car_details.fuel,
  car_details.engine,
  car_details.ps;
```

PD: I didn't test it, so it is on your own to confirm if it is enough.

Hugs!